# Put a GIF inside a Bootstrap header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Example: [last.fm](https://www.last.fm/music/osquinn)

```css
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

.b-example-divider {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0.125em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.b-example-vr {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -0.125em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  background-color: #151b29;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.navLinks {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.navLinks:hover {
  color: #ffa260;
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}

.osquinnHeader {}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
      <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z"
        />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="speedometer2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4zM3.732 5.732a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.915.914a.5.5 0 1 1-.708.708l-.914-.915a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.707zM2 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.586a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 10zm9.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm.754-4.246a.389.389 0 0 0-.527-.02L7.547 9.31a.91.91 0 1 0 1.302 1.258l3.434-4.297a.389.389 0 0 0-.029-.518z"
        />
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M0 10a8 8 0 1 1 15.547 2.661c-.442 1.253-1.845 1.602-2.932 1.25C11.309 13.488 9.475 13 8 13c-1.474 0-3.31.488-4.615.911-1.087.352-2.49.003-2.932-1.25A7.988 7.988 0 0 1 0 10zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-6.603 9.329c.203.575.923.876 1.68.63C4.397 12.533 6.358 12 8 12s3.604.532 4.923.96c.757.245 1.477-.056 1.68-.631A7 7 0 0 0 8 3z"
        />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="table" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm15 2h-4v3h4V4zm0 4h-4v3h4V8zm0 4h-4v3h3a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2zm-5 3v-3H6v3h4zm-5 0v-3H1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h3zm-4-4h4V8H1v3zm0-4h4V4H1v3zm5-3v3h4V4H6zm4 4H6v3h4V8z"
        />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="people-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z" />
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"
        />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="grid" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M1 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 5.5v-3zM2.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 5.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zM1 10.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 9h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 10.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 15h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 9h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5v3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"
        />
      </symbol>
    </svg>

<header>
  <div class="px-3 py-2 text-bg-dark osquinnHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
        <h4 class="d-flex align-items-center my-2 my-lg-0 me-lg-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
          Osquinn Fan Club
        </h4>
        <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto my-2 justify-content-center my-md-0 text-small">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link navLinks">
              <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#home" />
                  </svg> Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link navLinks">
              <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#speedometer2" />
                  </svg> Dashboard
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link navLinks">
              <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#table" />
                  </svg> Orders
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link navLinks">
              <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#grid" />
                  </svg> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link navLinks">
              <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#people-circle" />
                  </svg> Customers
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I've tried adding the `<img>` tag after the `osquinnHeader` class but the image just was too big and it didn't contain itself inside the header. It only made the header larger. I only want to contain a gif inside the header like the one in the example. I also tried checking the website's code but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `background-image: url(your-gif-image.gif)` to your header element?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74375590/edit) to show us how you attempted to add the GIF.